# Accurate summation of mixed-sign floating-point values

Tags: summation, numerical-methods

Due to the finite representation, floating-point addition loses significant bits. This is particularly noticeable when there is catastrophic cancellation, such that all the significant bits can disappear (e.g. $10^{-10}+10^{10}-10^{10}$).

Reordering the terms of the sum can improve accuracy. In particular, it is well-known that adding positive terms in increasing order is more accurate than otherwise, as the low-order bits are kept longer. I guess that this method is optimal or close to.

But for sums with both signs, is there a known strategy to improve the accuracy by reordering or grouping the terms ? Would separate summation of the positive and negative terms be a good idea (presumably not) ? Can we do better (with a reasonable increase in time complexity allowed) ?

**Update**:

I am quoting from the Higham reference given by @gammatester: "In designing or choosing a summation method to achieve high accuracy,
the aim should be to minimize the absolute values of the
intermediate sums ..." and " However, even if we concentrate on a specific set of data the aim is difficult to achieve, because minimizing the bound ... is known to be NP-hard".

Anyway, there seem to be good heuristics available.

Comment: Interesting question. Separate summation could still lead to cancellation if the sum is close to 0.

Comment: @flawr: certainly. anyway, different orders yield more or less accurate results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use compensated summation. Basically you can recover most of the error
from a single floating point addition. This was noticed long time ago by e.g. Dekker, Knuth, and others.

There are a lot of references, e.g.
T. Ogita, S.M. Rump, and S. Oishi, Accurate sum and dot product,
SIAM J. Sci. Comput., 26 (2005), pp. 1955-1988. Available as
http://www.ti3.tu-harburg.de/paper/rump/OgRuOi05.pdf

In chapter 4 of N.J. Higham, Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms, 2nd ed., Philadelphia, 2002,                     http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/asna/ compensated and other methods are described and analysed.

A simple fast method is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm

Comment: WOW: this is a dream answer ;-)